# assign statement in Questa Sim yields x as output

Tags: verilog, simulator, questasim

I wrote a module that should "or" a signal with a delayed version of itself. But, when I simulate my design, the output always goes x instead of 1. I have no idea why. Here is how I wrote my design:

```
module DUT(
input data_in,
input dw,
input rst,
output error
);
wire Edge;
wire #4 delayed_data_in;

assign Edge = data_in ^ delayed_data_in;
assign delayed_data_in = data_in;
always@(dw,Edge,rst) //Latch 1
begin
    if(rst)
    begin
        error <= 0;
    end
    else if(dw)
    begin
        error  <= Edge;
    end
end
endmodule
```

The delayed version behaves as expected, but `Edge` and `error` just go to "x" instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I get a compile error with your code.  You can try to compile your code on different simulators on edaplayground.  The problem is that you can not make a procedural assignment to a net (`error`).  To fix the error, change:

```
output error
```

to:

```
output reg error
```

With this simple testbench, the x's are resolved:

```
module tb;

    reg data_in;
    reg dw;
    reg rst;
    wire error;

DUT dut (
        // Inputs:
    .data_in  (data_in),
    .dw       (dw),
    .rst      (rst),
        // Outputs:
    .error    (error)
);

initial begin
    data_in = 0;
    dw = 0;
    rst = 1;
    #30 rst = 0;
    #50 $finish;
end

endmodule
```